# Has anyone successfully built a Cygwin version of GHC?

Tags: haskell, gcc, cygwin, mingw, ghc

Has anyone successfully built a Cygwin version of GHC (since Haskell switched from using Cygwin to MinGW)?

From the haskell website:

*"GHC targets MinGW, not Cygwin. It is in principle possible to build a version of GHC, GHC-cygwin, that targets Cygwin instead. The up-side of GHC-cygwin is that Haskell programs compiled by GHC-cygwin can import the (Haskell) Posix library. We do not support GHC-cygwin, however; it is beyond our resources."*
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Platforms/Windows

I tried, unsuccessfully, building with Cygwin's configure/gcc. This fails because I couldn't get the Windows version of GHC to use Cygwin's gcc.  This seems to be due to the fact that Windows' version of GHC is "registerised" and can't output c code.  Further, this "unregisterising-and-porting" method is [no longer supported.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Porting)

If anyone has accomplished this (since Haskell switched from using Cygwin to MinGW), I'd really like to know.  Instructions on how to do this would be great but if anyone has accomplished this a simple "yes" would be invaluable.

My latest attempt was with MinGW/MSys with the cross-compilation flag  `--target=i386-unknown-cygwin32`. This is the resulting error:

```
HSC2HS libraries/haskeline/dist-install/build/System/Console/Haskeline/Backend/Win32.hs
libraries\haskeline\System\Console\Haskeline\Backend\Win32.hsc:169 
directive let cannot be handled in cross-compilation mode
make[1]: *** [libraries/haskeline/dist-install/build/System/Console/Haskeline/Backend/Win32.hs] Error 1 make: *** 
[all] Error 2
```

Since programs need to be linked against `cygwin1.dll` I don't think setting the target to a Linux architecture would be useful.

Comment: "Has anyone done this" questions don't really fit the question/answer format of SO, where good questions should have a single "correct" answer. Can you reword this into, say, "I'm trying to build GHC on Cygwin, how do I get past <problem-stage>"? If you just want a general discussion on building GHC on Cygwin, you're better doing that on the Cygwin or GHC mailing lists.

Comment: I would note that there is nothing preventing you from running windows/mingw applications from cygwin terminal. of course, you won't get the posix library.

Comment: @IsaacHanson Cygwin and MinGW are different platforms. Running MinGW applications from Cygwin is like shoving a square peg [MinGW] into a cylindrical tube [Cygwin], which itself is shoved into a square hole [Windows]. Truly horrendous.