# Cabal failed to install unix-2.7.0.0

Tags: unix, haskell, cygwin, cabal

I'm trying to install unix package on windows environment. I'm using Cygwin, but its still not working.

Below is a snippet of the error I'm getting:

```
$ cabal install unix
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring unix-2.7.0.0...
Warning: Unknown extensions: CApiFFI, InterruptibleFFI
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking for gcc... gcc
.
.
.
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating unix.buildinfo
config.status: creating include/HsUnixConfig.h
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
cabal.exe: Package unix-2.7.0.0 can't be built on this system.
Failed to install unix-2.7.0.0
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
unix-2.7.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Perhaps you also need a Cygwin-aware GHC. GHC uses MinGW even when you run `ghc` from the Cygwin shell. You may need to compile GHC from source.

Comment: ...which seems to be highly non-trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367937/has-anyone-successfully-built-a-cygwin-version-of-ghc

Comment: "If a package depends (either directly or indirectly) on the unix package, you cannot compile it on Windows." - http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Windows

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is a partial linux toolset for windows, it's great if you need basic things but installing a full blown unix cabal plugin might be beyond its capabilities.
You may want to install a full linux os on a virtual machine (vagrant does great with this) or use a cloud real unix machine.
Linux hosts are really great to work with from remote

Happy codding