# GCC not working during compiling haskell programs on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, gcc, compilation, cygwin

I'd like to compile a Haskell project with a .cabal file under windows.

I have installed the Haskell Platform and Cygwin. One of the dependancies is `time`, which fail to build during the `cabal install` command.

The error message is the following:

```
checking for gcc... C:\PROGRA~1\HASKELL~1\826561~1.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
checking if the C compiler is working... no
configure error: C compiler cannot create executable
```

So I downloaded another `gcc` withing Cygwin that, I suppose, will work better. 
However, this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367937/has-anyone-successfully-built-a-cygwin-version-of-ghc) mention that the Haskell platform now uses MinGW rater than Cygwin to run GNU software.

I changed in the cabal `configure` file the location of `gcc`, but I still get the same error message (but with the new location of `gcc`).

So I'm a bit confused here: what is exactly the problem with `gcc`? Do you have any inputs on how I could continue the building of my software?

Comment: I would recommend starting up with Stack: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: I second Sibi. I installed Stack on Windows and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Using stack allowed me to progress further into the build. Thanks. I still have an issue but I think I'd better open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed (partially) by using Stack. Building is failing but for another reason, so I'll ask another question.

Thanks again.

Comment: You're getting the error with platform because you didn't follow step2 from https://www.haskell.org/platform/