# Stack fails to compile under windows

Tags: windows, haskell, compilation, glib, haskell-stack

I have a rather troublesome bug preventing me to build a small haskell project of mine under Windows, [which you can find here if you want to try to compile it](https://github.com/GirardR1006/syme).I am under cygwin64.

I'm using stack as a build helper, on the advice [given on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739930/gcc-not-working-during-compiling-haskell-programs-on-windows/47763092#47763092).
Now, the build is failing near at the end (which is rather frustrating after trying to do so for several hours).

Error message is the following:

```
setup.exe:
'C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE'
exited with an error:
cairo-0.13.4.2: Warning: haddock-interfaces:
C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\cairo-0.13.4.2\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\doc\html\cairo\cairo.haddock
doesn't exist or isn't a file
cairo-0.13.4.2: Warning: haddock-html:
C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\cairo-0.13.4.2\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\doc\html\cairo
doesn't exist or isn't a directory
cairo-0.13.4.2: include-dirs: /usr/include/cairo is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
cairo-0.13.4.2: include-dirs: /usr/include/glib-2.0 is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
cairo-0.13.4.2: include-dirs: /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include is a relative path
which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can
make paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
cairo-0.13.4.2: include-dirs: /usr/include/pixman-1 is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
cairo-0.13.4.2: include-dirs: /usr/include/freetype2 is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
cairo-0.13.4.2: include-dirs: /usr/include/libpng16 is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)


--  While building custom Setup.hs for package glib-0.13.5.0 using:
  C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: C:\cygwin64\home\Julien\syme-master\.stack-work\logs\glib-0.13.5.0.log

[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\glib-0.13.5.0\Setup.hs, C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( C:\sr\setup-exe-src\setup-shim-Z6RU0evB.hs, C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\StackSetupShim.o )
Linking C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack11608\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring glib-0.13.5.0...
Building glib-0.13.5.0...
In file included from C:/cygwin64/usr/include/glib/gtypes.h:34:0,
                 from C:/cygwin64/usr/include/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from C:/cygwin64/usr/include/glib.h:30,
                 from C:/cygwin64/usr/include/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from C:\cygwin64\home\Julien\syme-master\../../../usr/include\glib-object.h:23:
C:/cygwin64/usr/include/glib/gversionmacros.h:257:2: error: #error "GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED must be >= GLIB_VERSION_2_26"
 #error "GLIB_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED must be >= GLIB_VERSION_2_26"
  ^
Preprocessing library glib-0.13.5.0...
setup.exe: Error during preprocessing
```

The point is that according to cygwin installer, I have libglib2.0-devel version 2.52.3-1 installed. Is it the wrong version of glib2? Is there any conflict between other glib versions? If so, how can I make stack understand to check 
where are the correct versions?

I must say that I messed up a bit by adding relative paths inside of the stack.yaml file, I don't know if it is troublesome or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UDPATE: As the comments suggested, I changed my project-local stack.yaml to add the follwing (took me a while to figure out how to write the path on windows)

```
extra-include-dirs: [c;\\cygwin64\\usr\\include]
extra-lib-dirs: [c;\\cygwin64\\lib]
```

Inside of those, I unzipped the libs provided by the link user2407038 provided in the comments. Now, the error message looks like this:

```
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package cairo-0.13.4.2 using:
  C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\cairo-0.13.4.2\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: C:\cygwin64\home\Julien\syme-master\.stack-work\logs\cairo-0.13.4.2.log

[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\cairo-0.13.4.2\Setup.hs, C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\cairo-0.13.4.2\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( C:\sr\setup-exe-src\setup-shim-Z6RU0evB.hs, C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\cairo-0.13.4.2\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\StackSetupShim.o )
Linking C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\cairo-0.13.4.2\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring cairo-0.13.4.2...
Building cairo-0.13.4.2...
C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\cairo-0.13.4.2\cairo-gtk2hs.h:1:18: fatal error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Preprocessing library cairo-0.13.4.2...
setup.exe: Error during preprocessing


-- While building custom Setup.hs for package glib-0.13.5.0 using:
C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: C:\cygwin64\home\Julien\syme-master\.stack-work\logs\glib-0.13.5.0.log

[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\glib-0.13.5.0\Setup.hs, C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( C:\sr\setup-exe-src\setup-shim-Z6RU0evB.hs, C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\StackSetupShim.o )
Linking C:\cygwin64\tmp\stack10676\glib-0.13.5.0\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring glib-0.13.5.0...
Building glib-0.13.5.0...
Preprocessing library glib-0.13.5.0...
setup.exe: glib-object.h: File does not exist
```

Where can I find those headers?

Comment: Those are (afaik) not relative paths, but Unix/Linux paths, and apparently the compiler can not make sense out of these.

Comment: You can't really use cygwin with GHC, because on Windows GHC will expect to be in a Windows environment. In particular, there's nothing you can do to get GHC to recognize the path `/usr/include/cairo` as a valid Windows path (because it isn't). You have to install the native versions of glib (same goes for any other dependancy) and make sure that GHC not using cygwin `gcc` (stack does a good job of doing so, typically). Also note that your build is not failing near the end, it's doing so basically right at the start (when building a dependency, not even your package).

Comment: @user2407038 by native package, you mean Windows package? Because I looked for an available version of glib for Windows and I did not found out any...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/winlibs/glib) is the glib source; if you feel adventurous you can try to build it yourself. Otherwise you have to find pre-built binaries somewhere on the internet (a quick google search turns up [this](https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/glib/))

Comment: I would expect you could find detailed instructions for installing Stack from scratch on Windows. Did you dig around for those?

Comment: @user2407038 thanks, will try so.I have installed Stack with the Haskell platform for windows (https://www.haskell.org/platform/#windows)

Comment: FWIW, I can't say if this will address your particular problem, but so far, I've been running Stack exclusively from Git Bash on Windows, and I haven't run into problems with interoperability so far...

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the windows install instructions for gtk2hs: https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Installation#Windows

You can download the bundle directly (from https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php), or install it using the `pacman` distributed with the platform-installed msys distro.

You should use the msys version or the independent version, not the cywin one, as ghc is built to work with msys, not cygwin.

Once that's done you should be able to, having set up your paths correctly, `cabal install cairo`.